# How can I extract my AngularJS constants into a Typescript Function?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

My code has the following:

```
.service('testService', TestService)
.service('userService', UserService)
.constant("appConstant", {
    appName: "My App",
    appVersion: 2.0,
    baseUrl: "http://localhost:3048",
    Action: {
        None:0,
        Registering: 1,
        Authenticating: 2
    }
});
```

Is there a way I can extract the constant object into a different .ts file and include that?

Answer (score 8):

Yes. You can have the config in an external file. The simplest approach would be to do something like this:

```
class Constants
{
    static get Default():any {
        return {
            appName: "My App",
            appVersion: 2.0,
            baseUrl: "http://localhost:3048",
            Action: {
                None:0,
                Registering: 1,
                Authenticating: 2
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And then you can access it via `Constants.Default`. So your constant method in angular would look like:

```
.constant("appConstant", Constants.Default);
```

A more Typescript way would be to return types instead of the object literal in the default() getter. So you can go ahead and refactor my example to do that if you want.

Comment: How would you refactor this to return the types in the default getter?

Comment: Probably he meant to return an instance of concrete type instead of `any`.

Comment: not really as constant for typescript so no TS error with this